# JQuery Selector Table Cells

Tags: jquery, html-table, selector

I'm trying to get the value of the text box with the name `Promotion_26615` when the radio button named `RoomTypes[0].RoomOptionId` is clicked.

I've tried several selectors but nothing works. For example:

```
$('.radio').click(function () {
  var t = $(this)prev().prev().prev().prev().find("input[name*=Promotion_]").val();
});
```

And the html:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="roomtypeheader"><b>Free Nights - Stay 7 Pay 6 (Double Reethi)</b></td>
    <td data-title="Room Type" class="roomtypeheader">Reethi Villa</td>
    <td data-title="Board Type" class="roomtypeheader">Bed &amp; Breakfast</td>
    <td data-title="Price" class="roomtypeheader">$816.00 pp</td>
    <td data-title="Select" class="roomtypeheader">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="RoomTypes[0].RoomOptionId" value="a3fb34ee-4ec2-41cc-a093-be25ba75b0c9">
          <input type="hidden" name="RoomOptionPrice" value="816">
          <input type="hidden" name="RoomOptionChildPrice" value="0">
          <input type="hidden" name="NumberOfAdults" value="1">
          <input type="hidden" name="NumberOfChildren" value="0">
          <span class="hidden">option1</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Honeymoon Offer</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>$72.00</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Promotion_26615" value="72.0000" /></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use:

```
var t = $(this).closest('tr').next().find("input[name*=Promotion_]").val();
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2357zy4a/)**

[`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) won't work because that selects the previous sibling and you need an ancestor (which `.closest()` or `.parent()` or `.parents()` would select).

Comment: This nearly works however when I add a new row all the promotions are selected. I only want the promotions which are on the next three rows

Comment: Adding a new row wasn't part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've made a typo in your code:

`$(this)prev()` at the start should read `$(this).prev()` (missing full stop / period)

I think if you use the javascript console in whatever browser you're running the code in, you'll see a syntax error.

Assuming the `prev()prev().prev().prev().prev()` part of your code is intended for traversing the DOM back to the parent `form` element, the below would be more appropriate:

```
$('.radio').click(function() {
  var t = $(this).parents('form').find('input[name*="Promotion_"]').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find among siblings of the parent row:

```
var t = $(this).parents('tr').siblings().find("input[name*=Promotion_]").val();
```